# How to make this method generic in Scala

Tags: scala

This is a simple function which given an index, look up the item in an array from last

e.g. given `val arr = Array(1,2,3)` and `val i = 0`; it will return `3`

```
  def findIndexFromLast(arr: Array[Relationship], i: Int): Relationship = {
    val cur = i
    val size = arr.length

    arr(size - i - 1)
  }
```

I want to make it generic and be able to accept Array of any type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the 1st argument a `Seq()`, it will take many different types of collections as input.

```
def fromEnd[T](coll: Seq[T], index: Int):T = coll.reverse(index)

fromEnd(Array(1,3,5,7,9), 0)                 // res0: Int = 9
fromEnd(List('x','y','q','b'), 3)            // res1: Char = x
fromEnd(Vector(2.2, 5.4, 7.7), 2)            // res2: Double = 2.2
fromEnd(Stream(true, true, false, true), 1)  // res3: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def findIndexFromLast[A](arr: Array[A], i: Int): A = {
    val cur = i
    val size = arr.length

    arr(size - i - 1)
}
```